# RegularExpressionValidator on ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, regex

I know that there is a built in validation control on asp.net that can be use to validate internet email address.

The code is:

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" 
        ErrorMessage="RegularExpressionValidator" 
        ValidationExpression="\w+([-+.']\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

I know it is created by Microsoft but I want to know if this is the best to use regex for validating email address.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Try reading this

[How To Validate Email Address](http://haacked.com/archive/2007/08/21/i-knew-how-to-validate-an-email-address-until-i.aspx)

Comment: Link-only answers such as these are better posted as comments. (That said, it's a very good link.)

Comment: Oh sorry. Ill try to remember that next time. Tnx :)